# LTProf suitability with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, profiler

I have gotten recommendations from my earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860602/recommended-open-source-profilers) that LTProf may be a good low-cost option, especially if I'm profiling my application which is built for Windows machines only. After reading the description [here](http://www.lw-tech.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=25), I'm wondering if this application would work with Visual Studio rather than Visual C++. It would be great to hear some comments about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would, and maybe it wouldn't.

In case what you *really* want to know is "What is a good way to find performance problems in my application?" then I can give you a good answer - [consider this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Comment: Thanks. I found that I can run the executable given that it is compiled from C++ or Visual Basic. Thanks for your remarks about finding out a good way to find performance problems in an application.